# Video Player not loading upon return from modal

Tags: ios, swift, jwplayer

I am working on an iOS app with XCode 9.3 and Swift 4.

I have a setup where I have a screen, Episode view, with information on a particular video.

For a user that is not logged in, The screen contains:

- an image at the top
- underneath the image information about the video and a small description.
- a Sign in button

The Sign In button opens a modal. Whenever a
   user taps on this button, the user should be signed in and then return to the Episode view where the image should be replaced by a video
   player (we use JW) with the respective episode.

I created a delegate that would call a method in the EpisodeViewController upon signing in:

```
func refreshTopView() {
    subscribed = 1
    setUpTopView()
    print("View has refreshed")
}
```

Upon logging in, the delegate calls `setUpTopView()`

```
func setUpTopView() {

    if subscribed == 1 {

        // Hide the image view
        episodeImage.isHidden = true

        // Set up URL to video
        let linktoJSON = "https://content.jwplatform.com/feeds/" + (episode?.interviewKey)! + ".json";

        // Set video screen flag to true
        videoScreen = true

        // Get the feed for the video
        getFeed(url: linktoJSON)

    } else {

        // Hide the container view for the video
        containerView.isHidden = true

        // Get the show path and image file and set up the url
        let showPath = episode?.showPath
        let imageFile = episode?.imageFile
        let url = "https://examplesite.com/ios/images/" + showPath! + "/slider/" + imageFile! + ".jpg"

        // Show the image
        episodeImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url))

    }
}
```

which in turn calls `getFeed()` since the user has been verified as subscribed

```
func getFeed(url: String) {
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        .requestWithoutCache(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            self.buildPlaylistSources(json: json)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This will call the function to build the playlist for the JW Player,

```
func buildPlaylistSources(json: JSON) {
    playlistSources = [[String:String]]()

    if let playlistItems = json["playlist"].array {

        for item in playlistItems {
            if let sources = item["sources"].array {
                // For each source
                var tempSource = [String:String]()

                for source in sources {
                    if let sourceType = source["type"].string {
                        if sourceType.hasPrefix("video"){
                            let key = source["label"].stringValue
                            let value = source["file"].stringValue
                            tempSource[key] = value
                        }
                    }
                }
                playlistSources.append(tempSource)
            }
        }
        createPlayer()
    }
}
```

and subsequently set up the player and add it to the screen

```
func createPlayer() {
    let config: JWConfig = JWConfig()

    let showPath = episode?.showPath
    let imageFile = episode?.imageFile
    let videoImage = "https://examplesite.com/ios/images/" + showPath! + "/slider/" + imageFile! + ".jpg"


    for playlistSource in playlistSources {
        let item = JWPlaylistItem()

        var sourceArray = [JWSource]()

        for (key, value) in playlistSource {
            sourceArray.append(JWSource(file: value, label: key))
        }

        item.sources = sourceArray
        item.image = videoImage

        playlist.append(item)
    }


    config.playlist = playlist
    config.controls = true



    player = JWPlayerController(config: config)
    player.delegate = self

    let frame: CGRect = containerView.bounds

    self.player.view.frame = frame
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleLeftMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleRightMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleTopMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth]

    self.player.forceFullScreenOnLandscape = true
    self.player.forceLandscapeOnFullScreen = true

    containerView.addSubview(player.view)

    print("jwplayer")
}
```

Even though the code is running all the way to the end, and the initial image is hidden, the player is never loaded. If however I then navigate to a different section and then return to the Episode view, the video loads without issues. Also, if the user runs the app while having previously logged in, the videos load fine. It's just upon returning from the modal login screen that the video player won't load.

I checked the output screen and got the following:

```
2018-04-11 08:52:54.515047-0500 MyAppIOS[8506:1047732] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationContext]_block_invoke
2018-04-11 08:52:54.515273-0500 MyAppIOS[8506:1047732] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext createOutputContextWithUniqueIdentifier:]
2018-04-11 08:52:57.476625-0500 MyAppIOS[8506:1050590] [0x7f95a686f000] Decoding failed with error code -1
2018-04-11 08:52:57.476904-0500 MyAppIOS[8506:1050590] [0x7f95a686f000] Decoding: C0 0x02800168 0x0000354A 0x11111100 0x00000000 16384
2018-04-11 08:52:57.477102-0500 MyAppIOS[8506:1050590] [0x7f95a686f000] Options: 640x360 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00024060
```

Comment: Upon a going to the VC the first time (not logged in) you set `containerView.isHidden = true`. you Probably should set this to false somewhere if you want it to show back up. Which is why I assume it works if you reload the VC.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Its alright I'm pretty sure everyone in iOS has spent an hour two scratching their head wondering why their view that they themselves set to hidden isn't showing! haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by NSGangster in the comments:

Upon a going to the VC the first time (not logged in) you set containerView.isHidden = true. you Probably should set this to false somewhere if you want it to show back up. Which is why I assume it works if you reload the VC.